# Retargeting whole solution to another SDK using pre-build events

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that needs to be built by msbuild.exe, but I'm calling the msbuild.exe as a pre-build event of another soultion:

```
msbuild.exe $(ProjectDir)dependencies\submodule.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)
```

However, all 24 projects of the solution are targeting 8.1 SDK where I need them to target one of the Win10 SDK, so I need a way to retarget all of the project as a pre-build event.

Is that achievable is any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Any property can be changed. Just use the macro.

This line will target the same SDK as the solution from which this is ran as an event:

```
msbuild.exe "$(ProjectDir)dependencies\submodule\submodule.sln" /t:Build /p:Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)
```

P.S. What the hell with the down votes, come on...

Comment: You could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: I wanted to, but two days had to pass first. Thanks for the reminder. :)

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT That's a good hack. But VS should have a context menu on solution to allow to achieve this !

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't able to modify the solution at all, since it was a part of another repo that I couldn't control.